# Updating snaps runs for ages after cloning HDD

Tags: update-manager, cloning

I have cloned my HDD drive due to a smart notification that my HDD will be halted. Everything seems to work correctly apart from the following:
When using software updater during the end of the update procedure there is an indication: 'updating snaps' which lasts for ages.

I am running ubuntu 20.04

Comment: How long is ages? 5 mins a month?

Comment: It may take up to an hour while before cloning it took only few minutes!